# How to modify the QtPurchasing.jar file?

Tags: qt, jar

I'm using the Qt Purchase module for supscriptions under Android. Now I found that only In-App-Purchase "consumable" and "unlockable" are possible, not "subscriptions". But there would exist a hack by modifying the file.

> \5.12.1\android_armv7\jar\QtPurchasing.jar

https://forum.qt.io/topic/98353/qt-purchasing-supports-subscriptions-on-android/5

Unfortunately in some of the latest versions this file changed from .java to .jar.
Is there a way to modify such files under Qt? Thxs...

Comment: Jar files aren't meant to be modified. You should track down the source (it's open source, right?) modify it and build a new jar file as needed.

Comment: Yes ur right, but I dont know how really? I think first compile the .javas to .class and then archive. Unfortunately I have no experience with .jars.

Comment: http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtpurchasing.git/tree/src/android/src/org/qtproject/qt5/android/purchasing?h=5.12.1